# Does the Back Stack contain activities of one Task or multiple Tasks?

Tags: android, android-activity, task, back-stack

If I start another activity, that activity may be created in another task. Is this activity in the same Back Stack as the one that created it? Or does every task has it's own Back Stack?

Answer (score 0):

> that activity may be created in another task

It depends on the launch mode you set to `Activity`, Default behavior when you start new activity it will be the same task. In case you use launch mode is "singleTask" it will create new in another task or bring the previous instance to `BackStack`. Finally, when you call `startActivity` it always the same `BackStack`.

You can check documents [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack#TaskLaunchModes), and this it visualizes when `startActivity` in another Task

[image]